# DISABLE the Horizontal Scroll

Tags: html, css

Ok for some reason my webpage scrolls from left to right and shows a lot of ugly space.

I have searched for results but they just made the scrollbar **HIDDEN**

That's now what I want, I want to physically **DISABLE** the horizontal scroll feature. I do not want the user to be able to scroll left to right on my page just up and down!

I have tried: `overflow-x:hidden` in css on my `html` tag but it only made the scrollbar hidden and did not disable the scroll.

Please help me!

<strike>Here is a link to the page: http://www.green-panda.com/usd309bands/</strike> (Broken link)

This might give you a better idea of what I am talking about:

This is when the first pages loads:

[image]

And this is after I scroll to the right:

[image]

Comment: How can you scroll horizontally if there is no horizontal scrollbar?

Comment: Two fingers on the mouse going left to right on a laptop.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what on your page creates a default scrollbar?

Comment: How to scroll without a scrollbar? Middle-wheel-click drag on Windows.

Comment: there must be a block which will be having extra padding i.e extending the 100% width removing that would be a good practice

Answer (score 731, accepted):

Try adding this to your CSS

```
html, body {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: That worked great. I'm glad I found someone that understood what I was saying! I will accept as soon as I can.

Comment: In Chrome 34 this doesn't really prevent scrolling. It hides the scrollbar, but with middle-button scrolling I can still see the hidden elements on the left.

Comment: This doesn't work when you minimise the browser window to it's thinest capacity

Comment: only html works, you include body, another scrollbar appears

Comment: :-/ Caused touch / momentum scrolling to stop working on iPhone

Comment: This appears to be fixed in Chrome 49.

Comment: I've seen this happen on one of my pages, only with the I-phone Chrome, and this fixed the problem.  I'd like to mention a version, but I can't find ANY version info anywhere.

Comment: This breaks sticky positioning.

A new method that worked for me was `contain: paint;` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/contain

Comment: This prevents the bootstrap navbars from following the screen. To be precise, the 'html' selector causes this, it must be removed to fix the BS navbars.

It still works as intended with only the 'body' selector.

Answer (score 25):

You can try this all of method in our html page..

1st way

```
body { overflow-x:hidden; }
```

2nd way
You can use the following in your CSS body tag:

```
overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden;
```

That will remove your scrollbar.

3rd way

```
body { min-width: 1167px; }
```

5th way

```
html, body { max-width: 100%; overflow-x: hidden; }
```

6th way

```
element { max-width: 100vw; overflow-x: hidden; }
```

4th way..

```
var docWidth = document.documentElement.offsetWidth; [].forEach.call( document.querySelectorAll('*'), function(el) { if (el.offsetWidth > docWidth) { console.log(el); } } );
```

Now i m searching about more..!!!!

Comment: 5th way works nicely

Answer (score 22):

There is an approach in javascript that can help you detect which html element is causing the horizontal overflow -> scrollbar to appear

Here is a link to the post on [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/findingfixing-unintended-body-overflow/)

```
var docWidth = document.documentElement.offsetWidth;
[].forEach.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('*'),
  function(el) {
    if (el.offsetWidth > docWidth) {
      console.log(el);
    }
  }
);
```

it Might return something like this:

```
<div class="class-of-the-div-with-extra-width">...</div>
```

then you just remove the extra width from the `div` or set it's `max-width:100%`

Hope this helps!

It fixed the problem for me :]

Comment: As a site note, boundingClientRect is more precise than offsetWidth:
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43537559/javascript-getboundingclientrect-vs-offsetheight-while-calculate-element-heigh

Comment: absolute life saver!

Answer (score 19):

So to fix this properly, I did what others here did and used css to get hide the horizontal toolbar:

```
.name {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Then in js, I created an event listener to look for scrolling, and counteracted the users attempted horizontal scroll.

```
var scrollEventHandler = function()
{
  window.scroll(0, window.pageYOffset)
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollEventHandler, false);
```

I saw somebody do something similar, but apparently that didn't work. This however is working perfectly fine for me.

Comment: This works for me; however there is a jitter on mobile when swiping; while the motion slows down.

Comment: "properly" Not quite, but still a good and creative answer.

Comment: Beautiful. In my case (which should have a horizontally scrollable div within a non-horizontally-scrollable page) the `html, body {max-width: 100%; overflow-x:hidden;}` was preventing horizontal scroll, but also causing a big white chunk to appear on the bottom of my screen.  The javascript above allowed me to prevent horizontal scroll of the page without getting the big-white-bar.

Answer (score 15):

this is the nasty child of your code :)

```
.container, .navbar-static-top .container, .navbar-fixed-top .container, .navbar-fixed-bottom .container {
width: 1170px;
}
```

replace it with

```
.container, .navbar-static-top .container, .navbar-fixed-top .container, .navbar-fixed-bottom .container {
width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 14):

koala_dev answered that this will work:

```
html, body {
   max-width: 100%;
   overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

And MarkWPiper comments that ":-/ Caused touch / momentum scrolling to stop working on iPhone"

The solution to keep touch / momentum on iPhone is to add this line inside the css block for html,body:

```
    height:auto!important;
```

Comment: where to put it? under body tag or a media query for small screens?

Comment: @Umair thanks - edited comment to clarify that the height: auto line goes in the html,body css block.

Comment: Thank you very much for the height: auto solution!

Answer (score 9):

Try this one to disable width-scrolling just for body
the all document just is body
`body{overflow-x: hidden;}`

Answer (score 8):

If you want to disable horizontal scrolling over the entire screen width, use this code.

```css
element {
  max-width: 100vw;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

This works better than "100%" because it ignores the parent width and instead uses the viewport.

Answer (score 3):

Koala_dev's answer will work, but in case you are wondering this is the reason why it works:

```
.
q.html, body {              <--applying this css block to everything in the
                             html code.

q.max-width: 100%;          <--all items created must not exceed 100% of the 
                             users screen size. (no items can be off the page 
                             requiring scroll)

q.overflow-x: hidden;       <--anything that occurs off the X axis of the 
                             page is hidden, so that you wont see it going 
                             off the page.
```

.

Comment: Thx, I loved the education.

Answer (score 3):

I just had to deal with it myself. After all I found this method most easy and useful.
Just add

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

To your outer parent. In my case it looks like this:

```
<body style="overflow-x: hidden;">
```

You have to use `overflow-x` because if you use simply use `overflow` you disable the vertical scrolling too, namely `overflow-y`

If the vertical scrolling is still disabled you can enable it explicitly with:

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

I know its somewhat not a proper way because if everything was setup well one would not have to use this quick and dirty method.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the body scroll event with JavaScript, and reset the horizontal scroll to 0.

```
function bindEvent(e, eventName, callback) {
    if(e.addEventListener) // new browsers
        e.addEventListener(eventName, callback, false);
    else if(e.attachEvent) // IE
        e.attachEvent('on'+ eventName, callback);
};

bindEvent(document.body, 'scroll', function(e) {
    document.body.scrollLeft = 0;
});
```

I don't advise doing this because it limits functionality for users with small screens.

Comment: I'm going to try this out, the CSS fix does not work on my project, ugh even this doesn't work :(

Comment: this doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

```
.name 
  { 
      max-width: 100%; 
       overflow-x: hidden; 
   }
```

You apply the above style or you can create function in *javaScript* to solve that problem