# Website doesn't properly scroll (not fluid) & back-to-top fails

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari, overflow

I have a few scrolling related issues on the website I'm working on: http://wvg.lexerim.com

Since I implemented the twitter ticker on top I could scroll to the right, to solve this I used the most upvoted solution in this thread: [DISABLE the Horizontal Scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17756649/disable-the-horizontal-scroll) (others didn't work).

This solution however results in the following two problems:
- Scrolling isn't fluid anymore (especially on mobile devices)
- The back-to-top button doesn't work anymore <- this isn't important, can simple disable it

Do you guys have any solutions for either the fluid scrolling or a cleaner solution for the horizontal scrolling problem?

---

Edit: additional information [trying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23697830/website-doesnt-properly-scroll-not-fluid-back-to-top-fails/23699733?noredirect=1#23699733)I found out that the problem only exists in Safari and Chrome (and probably other webkit browsers) and not in firefox and that problem is caused by the overflow statements.

---

Edit 2: As this is apparently a Webkit (based) problem, two bug reports has been filled [Safari/Webkit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=132993) [Chromium](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=374301)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're better off going this way in the CSS:

```
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: scroll;
```

Also, perhaps webkit's overflow scrolling for touch may help?

[Momentum Scrolling on iOS Overflow Elements](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/momentum-scrolling-on-ios-overflow-elements/)

For what it's worth, just peeking at your site in Firefox, back-to-top is working for me. But yes, the scrolling with the scroll wheel is quite slow, and I don't see anything skimming through your code that should cause that.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried it and tested a bit (will edit the question in a sec). I do prefer your code but the response is almost identical. Scrolling on desktop works good enough now and back-to-top works in firefox. On safari and chrome though it doesn't and scrolling on my iPhone isn't fluid. On the moment I disable both the overflows scrolling is perfectly fine but I can scroll to the right... Maybe a webkit (and Chrome's fork) bug?

Comment: I believe you're right. IE doesn't have the problem; scrolling is perfect. I've got one more stab in the dark; a webkit attribute I kind of remember from some time ago. I'll hunt it down and modify my answer.

Comment: Another thought: do you have any Javascript elements that aren't loading in IE? Could it just be a matter of a JS performance bottleneck?

Comment: Just checked the source and I'm not seeing anything that isn't loaded in IE (or Firefox for this matter). I have a solution for scrolling on iOS. Disabling back-to-top for Safari and Chrome would be acceptable but of course isn't preferred.

Comment: Oh I see you already found the same source, killed my response :)

Comment: Apparently there was some cache, I can scroll to the right on my iPhone when using `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` :(