# Force browser to disable horizontal bar even when you ZOOMING in at 150%

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, scrollbar

How do i force the browser to disable horizontal bar even when you are viewing your web content at 125% - 150%?

Comment: try playing with the overflow proprety of <html> in css?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DISABLE the Horizontal Scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17756649/disable-the-horizontal-scroll)

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
html,body {
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

HTML:

For mobile devices, you probably need this meta tag in your `<head>`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

Answer (score -1):

This will disable when zoomed.  Add this to your CSS file.

```
html{overflow:hidden;}
```

Comment: No, this is not the correct answer, try zooming in your browser. You still can see the horizontal scroll bar! What i need is to FORCE DISABLE it regardless if there's content on the overflow right.