# Part of my django website looks worse on smartphone than rest, what is causing it?

Tags: android, html, css, django, responsive-design

I wanted to ask you for your help with my django website. I pushed my website to heroku, everything is working fine I think. Except "final view" on smartphones. On PC it is good, but on phone I am able to scroll a little bit horizontally and vertically.

I suppose that is because I used "zoom" css functions on my images to make them align how I wanted. But still, images were small I used zoom to make them bigger, not in the other way so it should be fine?

Can I somehow patch it without destroying rest of my work? I found this stackoverflow topic: [DISABLE the Horizontal Scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17756649/disable-the-horizontal-scroll/17756714) But "countering" user scrolling with JS looks like a plan "B" or "C" to me :P

Here are screenshots that shows my problem:

[image]
[image]

Here is template of this page:

```
    {% extends "builder/base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Robot Builder</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<!--Main jumbotron with all content inside-->
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="display-4">{{ robot_id }}
            <!--Button for reloading page to randomize robot elements again-->
            <br><button type="button" onClick="window.location.reload();" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="randomize">Randomize again!</button>
        </h1>
        <p class="lead">
            <br><br><center>
            <!--Comic bubble with message for user that appears over robot head-->
            <img src="{% static 'builder/comic_bubble.png' %}" alt="Comic Text Bubble" width="100" class="comic_bubble" id="comic_bubble"><br>
            <div id="comic_bubble_text">
        {{ message }}</p>
    </div>
    <!--Random robot head-->
    <img src="{% with 'builder/'|add:head_number as image_static %} {% static image_static %} {% endwith %}" alt="{{ head_number }}" class="robot_images" width="200" id="head"><br>
    <!--Random robot body#1-->
    {% if amount_body_elements > 0 %}
        <img src="{% with 'builder/'|add:body_element_1 as image_static %} {% static image_static %} {% endwith %}" alt="{{ body_element_1 }}" class="robot_images" width="200" id="{{ id_body_1 }}" onerror="this.style.display = 'none'"><br>
    {% endif %}
    <!--Random robot body#2-->
    {% if amount_body_elements > 1 %}
        <img src="{% with 'builder/'|add:body_element_2 as image_static %} {% static image_static %} {% endwith %}" alt="{{ body_element_2 }}" class="robot_images" width="200" id="{{ id_body_2 }}" onerror="this.style.display = 'none'"><br>
    {% endif %}
    <!--Random robot body#3-->
    {% if amount_body_elements > 2 %}
        <img src="{% with 'builder/'|add:body_element_3 as image_static %} {% static image_static %} {% endwith %}" alt="{{ body_element_3 }}" class="robot_images" width="200" id="{{ id_body_3 }}" onerror="this.style.display = 'none'"><br>
    {% endif %}
    <!--Random robot legs-->
    <img src="{% with 'builder/'|add:legs_number as image_static %} {% static image_static %} {% endwith %}" alt="{{ legs_number }}" class="robot_images" width="200" id="legs">
    <!--Clouds that appear when you refresh window to randomize robots element again. They are disappearing quickly.-->
    <div id="fadeout">
        {% if amount_body_elements > 1 %}
            <img src="{% with 'builder/'|add:cloud_number_1 as image_static %} {% static image_static %} {% endwith %}" alt="{{ cloud_number_1 }}" class="cloud" width="25" id="{{ id_cloud_1 }}" onerror="this.style.display = 'none'">
        {% endif %}
        <img src="{% with 'builder/'|add:cloud_number_2 as image_static %} {% static image_static %} {% endwith %}" alt="{{ cloud_number_2 }}" class="cloud" width="25" id="{{ id_cloud_2 }}" onerror="this.style.display = 'none'">
        <img src="{% with 'builder/'|add:cloud_number_3 as image_static %} {% static image_static %} {% endwith %}" alt="{{ cloud_number_3 }}" class="cloud" width="25" id="{{ id_cloud_3 }}" onerror="this.style.display = 'none'">
    </div>
    </center>
    <!--Javascript that I used for making cloud from before disappear after given amount of ms. Opacity from 1 to 0.-->
    <script>
function displayOut() {
    var a = document.getElementById('id_cloud_1');
    setTimeout(function(){
        a.style.opacity='0';
    }, 200);
    var b = document.getElementById('id_cloud_2');
    setTimeout(function(){
        b.style.opacity='0';
    }, 300);
    var c = document.getElementById('id_cloud_3');
    setTimeout(function(){
        c.style.opacity='0';
    }, 400);
}
displayOut();
    </script>
</div>

</body>
</html>

{% endblock %}
```

Thank you, Cheers

Comment: you can ad media queries to your css. https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your css file you can set your body to width: 100vw & overflow-x: hidden

should fix the sidescroll issue! No need to use JS for that!