# How to prevent overscrolling problem with webpage

Tags: html, css

I am facing a problem where my simple HTML page (with some album covers on the left and a user list on the right like Spotify) over scrolls. I have tried all options with the overscroll-behavior property with no luck.

It works fine with just the album covers or the user list. It starts over scrolling as soon as I add both.

```css
body {
    font-family: '';
    background-color: #000000;
    width: 600px;
    margin: auto;
    border-left: 1px solid #000000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000000;
    padding: 10px;
    background-image: url("background.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    /* from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17756649/disable-the-horizontal-scroll --> to
    disable horizontal scroll/page moving from left to right*/
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

/* top part/beginning of webpage */

#user {
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 
    Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: medium;
    color: #0cb004;
    font-style: italic;
    position: relative;
    right: 400px;
}

#welcome {
    font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Impact', sans-serif;
    color: #0cb004;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative; right: 400px; 
}


#logo-text {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    top: -200px;
    left: 600px;
    font-size: smaller;
}

#fake-logo {
    position: relative;
    top: -245px;
    left: 980px;
    width: 40px;
}

#search-bar {
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 8px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 20px; 
    position: relative; top: -90px; left: 520px;
}

/* divider */

#first-divider {
    border-top: 5px solid white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    top: -25px;
}

/* h2s - start being used here (all h2s share some features in common) */

.h2 {
    color: white;
    font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: lighter;
}

/* friend activity on the right side */

#friends-list {
    position: relative;
    top: -70px;
    left: 800px;
}

/* classes used to eliminate redundancy in code - all friend list elements share some features in common */

.username {
    color: #0cb004;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.activity {
    color: white;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
}

#first-friend-name {
    position: relative;
    top: -50px;
    left: 800px;
}

#first-friend-activity {
    position: relative;
    top: -50px;
    left: 800px;
}

#second-friend-name {
    position: relative;
    top: -30px;
    left: 800px;
}

#second-friend-activity {
    position: relative;
    top: -30px;
    left: 800px;
}

#third-friend-name {
    position: relative;
    top: -10px;
    left: 800px;
}

#third-friend-activity {
    position: relative;
    top: -10px;
    left: 800px;
}

#fourth-friend-name {
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    left: 800px;
}

#fourth-friend-activity {
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    left: 800px;
}

#fifth-friend-name {
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
    left: 800px;
}

#fifth-friend-activity {
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
    left: 800px;
}

#sixth-friend-name {
    color: gray;
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    left: 800px;
}

#sixth-friend-activity {
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    left: 800px;
}

#seventh-friend-name {
    color: gray;
    position: relative;
    top: 70px;
    left: 800px;
}

#seventh-friend-activity {
    position: relative;
    top: 70px;
    left: 800px;
}

#eighth-friend-name {
    color: gray;
    position: relative;
    top: 90px;
    left: 800px;
}

#eighth-friend-activity {
    position: relative;
    top: 90px;
    left: 800px;
}

#ninth-friend-name {
    color: gray;
    position: relative;
    top: 110px;
    left: 800px;
}

#ninth-friend-activity {
    position: relative;
    top: 110px;
    left: 800px;
}

/* first listening section - "Jump Back In..." */

#first-header {
    position: relative; 
    top: -820px; 
    right: 400px;
}

/* classes used to eliminate redundancy in code - all playlist elements share some features in common */

.playlist-name {
    color: #0cb004;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.playlist-description {
    color: white;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.playlist-picture {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

#playlist-one-pic {
    position: relative;
    top: -800px;
    right: 400px;
}

#playlist-one-name {
    position: relative;
    top: -810px;
    right: 400px;
}

#playlist-one-description {
    position: relative;
    top: -820px;
    right: 400px;
}

#playlist-one-play-button {
    width: 50px;
    position: relative;
    top: -1100px;
    right: 400px;
}

#playlist-two-pic {
    position: relative;
    top: -1100px;
    right: 75px;
}

#playlist-two-name {
    position: relative;
    top: -1110px;
    right: 22px;
}

#playlist-two-description {
    position: relative;
    top: -1120px;
    right: 22px;
}

#playlist-two-play-button {
    width: 50px;
    position: relative;
    top: -1415px;
    right: 22px;
}

#playlist-three-pic {
    position: relative;
    top: -1415px;
    left: 290px;
}

#playlist-three-name {
    position: relative;
    top: -1425px;
    left: 340px;
}

#playlist-three-description {
    position: relative;
    top: -1435px;
    left: 340px;
}

#playlist-three-play-button {
    width: 50px;
    position: relative;
    top: -1560px;
    left: 345px;
}

/* divider */
/* peer feedback from in-class 9/23 - changed position of divider so it was
more centered between content */

#second-divider {
    border-top: 5px solid white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    top: -1400px;
}

/* second listening section - "Trending Albums For You" */

#second-header {
    font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
    position: relative; 
    top: -1350px; 
    right: 400px;
}

/* classes used to eliminate redundancy in code - all album elements share some features in common */
.album-cover {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.album-name {
    color: #0cb004;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

.album-description {
    color: white;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#first-album-cover {
    position: relative;
    top: -1320px;
    right: 400px;
}

#first-album-name {
    position: relative;
    top: -1320px;
    right: 400px;
}

#first-album-description {
    position: relative;
    top: -1330px;
    right: 400px;
}

#album-one-play-button {
    width: 50px;
    position: relative;
    top: -1610px;
    left: -400px;
}

#second-album-cover {
    position: relative;
    top: -1310px;
    right: 450px;
}

#second-album-name {
    position: relative;
    top: -1315px;
    right: 400px;
}

#second-album-description {
    position: relative;
    top: -1325px;
    right: 400px;
}

#album-two-play-button {
    width: 50px;
    position: relative;
    top: -1595px;
    right: 395px;
}

#third-album-cover {
    position: relative;
    top: -1890px;
}

#third-album-name {
    position: relative;
    top: -1895px;
    right: -53px;
}

#third-album-description {
    position: relative;
    top: -1905px;
    right: -55px;
}


#album-three-play-button {
    width: 50px;
    position: relative;
    top: -2173px;
    right: -50px;
}

#fourth-album-cover {
    position: relative;
    top: -1880px;
}

#fourth-album-name {
    position: relative;
    top: -1885px;
    right: -53px;
}

#fourth-album-description {
    position: relative;
    top: -1895px;
    right: -55px;
}


#album-four-play-button {
    width: 50px;
    position: relative;
    top: -2163px;
    right: -50px;
}

#fifth-album-cover {
    position: relative;
    top: -2300px;
    left: 405px;
}

#fifth-album-name {
    position: relative;
    top: -2305px;
    left: 458px;
}

#fifth-album-description {
    position: relative;
    top: -2315px;
    left: 458px;
}


#album-five-play-button {
    width: 50px;
    position: relative;
    top: -2430px;
    left: 457px;
}

/* divider */
#third-divider {
    border-top: 5px solid white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    top: -2200px;
}

#div-1 {
    height: min-content;
}


/* see more button at bottom of website */
#see-more {
    position: relative;
    top: -2200px;
    left: 230px;
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #0cb004;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<!--head -> title of page Music Player™ and linking CSS to HTML-->
<head>

    <title>Music Player™</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/style.css"/>

</head>

<!-- start of body -->
<body>

    <!-- h1s - states user and gives welcome message-->
    <h1 id = "user">@USER Me! -- ONLINE!</h1>
    <h1 id = "welcome"> Good Morning. What would you like to listen to today?</h1>

    <!-- creates search bar-->
    <p id="search-bar">Search artists, playlists, albums, and more...</p>

    <!-- first divider (use CSS to make it rounded), placed here for formatting-->
    <hr id="first-divider">

    <!-- creates fake logo and slogan in top right-->
    <p id="logo-text">The premier music playing software... Music Player™!</p>
    <img src = "static/fakespotifylogo.png" id = "fake-logo">

    
    <!-- creates friend activity feature on the right side; there is a username - belongs to class username -
        and their activity - belongs to class activity - for each person-->
    <h2 class = "h2" id = "friends-list">Friend Activity</h2>

    <p class = "username" id = "first-friend-name">@user1 -- ONLINE!</p>
    <p class = "activity" id = "first-friend-activity">Love Him I Don't ● Maisie Peters <br> ♫ You Signed 
        Up For This</p>

    <p class = "username" id = "second-friend-name">@user12 -- ONLINE!</p>
    <p class = "activity" id = "second-friend-activity">RUNNING OUT OF TIME ● Tyler, <br> The Creator <br> ♫ IGOR </p>

    <p class = "username" id = "third-friend-name">@user13 -- ONLINE!</p>
    <p class = "activity" id = "third-friend-activity">Lucid Dream ● aespa <br> ♫ Savage </p>

    <p class = "username" id = "fourth-friend-name">@user14 -- ONLINE!</p>
    <p class = "activity" id = "fourth-friend-activity">Can I Call You Tonight? ● Dayglow <br> ♫ Fuzzybrain </p>

    <p class = "username" id = "fifth-friend-name">@user120 -- ONLINE!</p>
    <p class = "activity" id = "fifth-friend-activity">Wrong Decisions ● NAV <br> ♫ Demons Protected by Angels</p>

    <p class = "username" id = "sixth-friend-name">@user15 :) -- OFFLINE!</p>
    <p class = "activity" id = "sixth-friend-activity">Guns and Ships ●  Original Broadway Cast <br> of Hamilton <br> 
        ♫ Hamilton (Original Broadway Cast <br> Recording)</p>

    <p class = "username" id = "seventh-friend-name">@user16 -- OFFLINE!</p>
    <p class = "activity" id = "seventh-friend-activity">Moment 4 Life ● Nicki Minaj, Drake <br> ♫ Pink Friday</p>

    <p class = "username" id = "eighth-friend-name">@user17 -- OFFLINE!</p>
    <p class = "activity" id = "eighth-friend-activity">Stitches ● Shawn Mendes <br> ♫ Handwritten </p>

    <p class = "username" id = "ninth-friend-name">@user19! - OFFLINE!</p>
    <p class = "activity" id = "ninth-friend-activity">All Too Well (10 Minute Version)<br>(Taylor's Version) ● Taylor Swift
    <br> ♫ Red (Taylor's Version) </p>
    
    <!-- new div for a new section -->
    <div>

    <!-- creates first section for listening - jump back in (to recent playlists)
    each playlist has a name, time last listened, a cover picture, and a few songs in it-->
    <h2 class = "h2" id = "first-header">Jump Back In...</h2>
    
    <img src = "static/sadkermit.jpg" class = "playlist-picture" id = "playlist-one-pic">
    <p class = "playlist-name" id = "playlist-one-name">3 am thoughts ● 1:03 AM</p>
    <p class = "playlist-description" id = "playlist-one-description">with Memories ● Conan Gray, Solo ● Frank Ocean, <br> 
        N Side ● Steve Lacy, & more
    </p>
    <img src = "static/spotifyplaybutton.png" id = "playlist-one-play-button">

    <img src = "static/kermithappy.jpg" class = "playlist-picture" id = "playlist-two-pic">
    <p class = "playlist-name" id = "playlist-two-name">serotonin!! ● 4:13 PM</p>
    <p class = "playlist-description" id = "playlist-two-description">with The Spins ● Mac Miller, Love Grows (Where <br>
        My Rosemary Grows) ● Edison Lighthouse, Ykwim? <br>
         ● Yot Club, & more 
    </p>
    <img src = "static/spotifyplaybutton.png" id = "playlist-two-play-button">

    <img src = "static/kermitstudy.jpg" class = "playlist-picture" id = "playlist-three-pic">
    <p class = "playlist-name" id = "playlist-three-name">seeking academic validation. ● 10:47 PM</p>
    <p class = "playlist-description" id = "playlist-three-description">with willow ● Taylor Swift, Je te laisserai de mots <br>
        ● Patrick Watson, astroboy. ● suggi, & more
    </p>
    <img src = "static/spotifyplaybutton.png" id = "playlist-three-play-button">

    <!-- end div for new section -->
    </div>
    
    <!-- second divider (use CSS to make it rounded), placed here for formatting-->
    <hr id = "second-divider">

    <!-- new div for a new section -->
    <div id="div-1">

    <h2 class = "h2" id="second-header">Trending Albums For You</h2>

    <!-- creates second section for listening - trending albums for you
    each album has a name, artist, year released, and number of songs-->
    <img src = "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71UgVkCnalL._SL1200_.jpg" class = "album-cover" id = "first-album-cover">
    <p class = "album-name" id = "first-album-name">FOUR (Deluxe) ● One Direction</p>
    <p class = "album-description" id = "first-album-description">2014, 16 songs</p>
    <img src = "static/spotifyplaybutton.png" id = "album-one-play-button">

    <img src = "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b273decd839dd4fef3faf64c5fd5" class = "album-cover" id = "second-album-cover">
    <p class = "album-name" id = "second-album-name">Face The Sun ● SEVENTEEN</p>
    <p class = "album-description" id = "second-album-description">2022, 9 songs</p>
    <img src = "static/spotifyplaybutton.png" id = "album-two-play-button">

    <img src = "static/whocaresalbumcover.png" class = "album-cover" id = "third-album-cover">
    <p class = "album-name" id = "third-album-name">WHO CARES? ● Rex Orange County</p>
    <p class = "album-description" id = "third-album-description">2022, 11 songs</p>
    <img src = "static/spotifyplaybutton.png" id = "album-three-play-button">

    <img src = "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81NSetbGioL._SL1500_.jpg" class = "album-cover"
    id = "fourth-album-cover">
    <p class = "album-name" id = "fourth-album-name">Hozier ● Hozier</p>
    <p class = "album-description" id = "fourth-album-description">2014, 13 songs</p>
    <img src = "static/spotifyplaybutton.png" id = "album-four-play-button">

    <img src = "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b273e6d118f2ad157bf0bbfb83cf" class = "album-cover" id = 
    "fifth-album-cover">
    <p class = "album-name" id = "fifth-album-name">Hello Future ● NCT DREAM</p>
    <p class = "album-description" id = "fifth-album-description">2021, 13 songs</p>
    <img src = "static/spotifyplaybutton.png" id = "album-five-play-button">

    <!-- third divider (use CSS to make it rounded), placed here for formatting-->
    <hr id = "third-divider">

    <h2 class = "h2" id = "see-more">See More...</h2>
    
    <!-- end div for new section -->
    </div>

    

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have a lot of sizing in pixels that makes it only work well for a specific screen width. Maybe add CSS for other screen sizes or size in proportionate measures like `vw` `vh` or `em` instead.

Comment: using relative positions for almost every element on the page is a horrible idea, check out flexbox or grid concepts

Answer (score 0):

Create a layout but start thinking about a structure first. The layout consists of a header, a sidebar, some main content with rows or columns, and maybe also a navigation and a footer later. Read more about [layouts](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_website_layout.asp) and [semantic HTML elements](https://learn-the-web.algonquindesign.ca/topics/html-semantics-cheat-sheet/).

Here's an idea:

[image]

When your page structure is good, the rest will evolve, here are some tips I have learned during my journey:

- Wrap your content into pieces (maybe divs with classes, sections, etc).
- Only use CSS classes to style elements. Reserve IDs for Javascript.
- Use good names for your classes.
- You can go ["mobile-first"](https://medium.com/@Vincentxia77/what-is-mobile-first-design-why-its-important-how-to-make-it-7d3cf2e29d00).
- You can use [media queries for bigger screen sizes](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp).
- You can use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)  (which is not the easiest concept for beginners) to position elements in rows or columns.
- Watch something like [Kevin Powell's series about creating a website](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h3bTwCqX4ns&list=PL4-IK0AVhVjNDRHoXGort7sDWcna8cGPA&index=1).

I included a sample media query for the new header using flexbox. The search box will move to the right and the h1 size will decrease (just resize the screen).

```css
body {
    font-family: '';
    background-color: #000000;
    margin: auto;
    border-left: 1px solid #000000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000000;
    padding: 10px;
    background-image: url("background.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.h2 {
    color: white;
    font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: lighter;
}

.user {
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 
    Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: medium;
    color: #0cb004;
    font-style: italic;
    position: relative;
}

.welcome {
    font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Impact', sans-serif;
    color: #0cb004;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    text-align: left;
}


.logo-text {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-size: smaller;
}

.fake-logo {
    position: relative;
    width: 40px;
}

.fake-search-bar {
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 8px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 20px; 
}

.divider {
    border-top: 5px solid white;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.username {
    color: #0cb004;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.activity {
    color: white;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
}

.playlist-name {
    color: #0cb004;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.playlist-description {
    color: white;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.playlist-picture {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .header {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Music Player™</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/style.css"/>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="header">
        <h1 class="user">@USER Me! -- ONLINE!</h1>
        <h1 class="welcome"> Good Morning. What would you like to listen to today?</h1>
        <div class="fake-search-bar"></div>
    </div>
    

    <hr class="divider">

    <p class="logo-text">The premier music playing software... Music Player™!</p>
    <img class="fake-logo" src="https://images.complex.com/complex/images/c_fill,dpr_auto,f_auto,q_90,w_1400/fl_lossy,pg_1/mqlimq5ifprz3klcoxpt/spotify-logo">

    <div class="sidebar">
        <h2 class="friends-header">Friend Activity</h2>
        <p class="first-friend-name">@user1 -- ONLINE!</p>
        <p class="first-friend-activity">Love Him I Don't ● Maisie Peters <br> ♫ You Signed 
            Up For This</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="main">
        <p>♫ Red (Taylor's Version) </p>
        <div>
            <p>Jump Back In...<p>
            
            <img class="playlist-picture" src="https://i.imgflip.com/1wr9we.jpg">
            <p class="playlist-name">3 am thoughts ● 1:03 AM</p>
            <p class="playlist-description">with Memories ● Conan Gray, Solo ● Frank Ocean, <br> 
                N Side ● Steve Lacy, & more
            </p>
            <img class="spotify-play-button" src="http://hypebot.typepad.com/.a/6a00d83451b36c69e201bb09b0b161970d-200wi">
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <hr class="divider">

    <div id="div-1">
        <h2>Trending Albums For You</h2>
        <img class="album-cover" src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71UgVkCnalL._SL1200_.jpg">
        <p class="album-name">FOUR (Deluxe) ● One Direction</p>
        <p> 2014, 16 songs</p>
        <img class="spotify-play-button" src="http://hypebot.typepad.com/.a/6a00d83451b36c69e201bb09b0b161970d-200wi">
        <img class="album-cover" src="https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b273decd839dd4fef3faf64c5fd5">
        <hr class="divider">
        <p class="see-more">See More...</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```